# Cannot use httpwebrequest with listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox, httpwebrequest

I am facing a strange problem with listbox. I need to scrab whois information. I used the following code to get source code of the whois query. It works fine if I use a textbox. But I need to use this for multiple url and therefore need to use lixtbox to loop through url list. Unfortunately when I use listbox1.selecteditem or listbox1.text it does not work. But this same code works with webbrowser.

Please help me solving this problem

```
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/results.jsp?domain=" & listbox1.selecteditem)
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)"
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim html As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
sr.Close()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happens because you don't dispose the previous response before processing the next one.

Your code should look like this:

```
Using response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    ' processing of the response
End Using
```

-- Pavel

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but I have not use looping. I just tried with single item manually selecting that item. But it does not work.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code. There should be listbox1.SelectedItem.Value (or listbox1.SelectedItem.Text depending on where on what do you need) instead of just passing the object reference representing selected item (in your case: listbox1.selecteditem). In the latter case a string representation of that object reference is returned instead of actual listbox value.

Comment: Hi, if I am not wrong there is no such code as listbox1.SelectedItem.Value or listbox1.SelectedItem.Text, it will show syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I thought you're using ASP.NET (apparently it's WinForms). What is the value of the listbox1.SelectedItem you're getting (please paste it from the debugger) ?